# Library sompy for implementing self-organizing maps

Tags: python, algorithm, libraries, som, self-organizing-maps

I have installed the library sompy, but when I import it I have the next error:

```
  import sompy
  
  ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-86-97d518356b3c> in <module>
  ----> 1 import sompy

  /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sompy/__init__.py in <module>
  1 
  ----> 2 from sompy import SOM

  ImportError: cannot import name 'SOM' from partially initialized module 'sompy' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sompy/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is explained [here](https://github.com/sevamoo/SOMPY/issues/61). The solution is to install a newer version of sompy:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/compmonks/SOMPY.git
```

There are also other, more up-to-date packages for SOMs available, for example [minisom](https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom) and [susi](https://github.com/felixriese/susi).

Comment: Thank you! The library minisom is only for small datasets, isn´t it?

Comment: SOMs are mostly for small to medium-sized datasets. The "mini" in minisom corresponds to the minimalistic implementation.

Comment: So if I have between 50.000 to 80.000 dates I need to use susi?

Comment: Should be fine for both. Just try them